# how do you use virtual-dom gist in browser?

Tags: javascript, git, dom

https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom uses require() to load scripts, how do I set this up if I want to use virtual-dom from the browser?  I tried including RequireJS [https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs] to do the require() handling but it removes all the script elements in my body.  The alert never happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/volojs/create-template/master/www/lib/require.js"/>
</head>
<body>

<script> <!-- this script block gets removed by requireJS -->
alert(1);
// from the example at https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom
var h = require('virtual-dom/h');    
var diff = require('virtual-dom/diff');
var patch = require('virtual-dom/patch');
var createElement = require('virtual-dom/create-element');
// 1: Create a function that declares what the DOM should look like
function render(count)  {
    return h('div', {
        style: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            lineHeight: (100 + count) + 'px',
            border: '1px solid red',
            width: (100 + count) + 'px',
            height: (100 + count) + 'px'
        }
    }, [String(count)]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try using browserify or webpack to adapt it for browser use?